# .NET micro framework deployment tool

Tags: .net, visual-studio, arm, .net-micro-framework

I want to connect to my AT91SAM9RL board with the .NET mfdeployment tool. It only has USB, [JTAG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joint_Test_Action_Group) and serial ports. It normally works fine when I use [PuTTY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PuTTY), Segger GDB or [SAM-BA](http://www.atmel.com/tools/ATMELSAM-BAIN-SYSTEMPROGRAMMER.aspx) (Atmel SAM-BA In-system Programmer).

For some reason the micro frameworks deployment tool can't find or connect to my board. Why?